# C# WPF -> context menu bounded command won't be called

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, scope, contextmenu

I have a little problem with wpf.
I have a listbox and in it a context menu,
but the bounded command won't be called if I am click on a menu item.

I think there is an error with the scope, but I dont have an idia to solve this problem, so I hope, that some guy here can help me.

Here is my code from the ui:

```
<ListBox Name="CompanyListBox" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Companys}">                   
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>              
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="LightGray" Margin="5">         
                            <Border.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Akt. Item in einem neuen Fenster öffnen" Command="{Binding Path=OpenInNewWindowCommand}">
                                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                                            <Image Width="24" Height="24" Source="path/to/icon/icon.ico"></Image>
                                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Border.ContextMenu>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">                               
                               //Here is the layout of the item
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

And here the code from the viewmodel:

```
    public ICommand OpenInNewWindowCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(OpenInNewWindow);
        }
    }
```

Yes, the DataContext are be setted to the view model, everything works excpet the context menu.

The method "OpenInNewWindow" will be not called from the ui if I clicked on the menu item, why?

(Sorry for bad englisch ;) I´m not from there ^^)

Comment: Check your binding errors in your output. You most likely bound to something that does not exist. Right now, each item of your Companys container is expected to have an OpenInNewWindowCommand. However, you probably implemented that on your ViewModel.

Comment: Yes, it's right, each item shoul can call OpenInNewWindow, so it's not a problem. Okay, I'll check the binding errors now, but I'm sure all binding names are correct, I've copy and pasted from the class.

Comment: Yes, but your `DataContext` has changed. It's no longer the Windows DataContext aka your ViewModel, but instead it switched to an item of the collection that is called Companys.

Comment: Okay this was my problem. Thank, now it works finde ;)